# Find every object of a specific type in an image using Google Cloud Vision

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

I want to detect every license plate in large photos using Google Vision and Nodejs, so that I can blur them and make them unreadable for privacy purposes.

```
const client = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const [result] = await client.objectLocalization(fileUrl);
return result.localizedObjectAnnotations;
```

The problem: This doesn't return every object in the image. It only returns a few. So if I filter on "License plate", I will not find every license plate in the picture. I have tried using textdetection like this:

```
const client = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileUrl);
return result.textAnnotations;
```

This works better, but there are still some license plates that are not detected. Those lisence plates are readable to the human eye. If I crop only the plate and runs it through the objectdetection function, the AI recognize it as a license plate.

To summarize: The vision API is capable of recognising license plates in small images with few objects, but I want to make a search to find absolutely every license plate in a large picture. Is this even possible with the Vision API?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Vision API, the **Object Localizatio**n feature is basically used to detect multiple objects inside an image. The reason you are using this feature and you are not getting all the license plates in the output is because in Vision API you can get a maximum of 10 objects per category in an image.

**E.g. -**

If an image has multiple categories like bikes, cycles, mobile phones etc. then using the Object Localization feature, you can get a maximum of 10 objects per category which means Cloud Vision API returns overall more than 10 objects rather than more than 10 objects with a specific category.

I tried your use case with an image where I have around 24 number plates in the image. When I tried to run the code and did the count, I got 10 objects for license plates.

You can look into the below code snippet and the relevant output :

```
async function localizeObjectsGCS(gcsUri) {
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

 const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
 const data =[]

 const [result] = await client.objectLocalization(gcsUri);
 const objects = result.localizedObjectAnnotations;
 objects.forEach(object => {
   console.log(`Name: ${object.name}`);
   data.push(`Name: ${object.name}`);
  
 });

console.log(data.length);  
}

localizeObjectsGCS(`gs://mybucket/img.jpg`)
```

**output:**

```
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
Name: License plate
10
```

Which means for every category you will have a maximum number of objects as per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer#try_it). In the response field there is a parameter called [maxResults](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature) where we can define the maximum number of objects per category but it should be less than or equal to 10.

If you want to use the Object Localization feature you must have images with at most 10 number plates, as per your use case.

Regarding the second point that you are applying the filter **License plate** and doing the text detection but not getting all the numbers in output, here instead of text detection you can also try using [document text detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#optical_character_recognition_ocr) which is optimised for dense texts.

You can refer to the below python snippet :

```
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
l1=[]
image = vision.Image()


response = client.annotate_image({
 'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'gs://mybucket/img.jpg'}},
 'features': [{'type_': vision.Feature.Type.OBJECT_LOCALIZATION},
 {'type_': vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION}
  ]
})

lo_annotations = response.localized_object_annotations
for obj in lo_annotations:
       if obj.name == 'License plate':
           for page in response.full_text_annotation.pages:
     
               for block in page.blocks:

                   for paragraph in block.paragraphs:

                       for word in paragraph.words:
                           words = ''.join([
                       symbol.text for symbol in word.symbols
                       ])
                           print('Words: {} (confidence: {})'.format(
                           words, word.confidence))
```

**output(a part of full output):**

[image]

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).